# EditPad Pro saves Python files as Batch file output ()

Tags: text-editors, batch-file

I am using EditPad Pro and my file type is set to Python. EditPad is great and I like it but recently I was trying to update Google App Engine and I got an error during installation saying that my python script contained non-ascii characters. [This is my question at Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479272/Google-app-engine-upgrade-error).

When I saved the file in Notepad as text the problem was solved. Then I noticed that EditPad was saving python file as `Batch file output()`. I believe that python file with .py ending needs to be saved as text. But `Batch file output()` is the default save for .py. Is there a way to change this setting? I tried to change it in Option-->Preferences but couldn't make it work. And also, is this the cause of the problem why there are non-ascii characters in the script?

Comment: As you are not having much luck getting an answer here, you should try emailing the author of EditPad Pro.  I emailed him many years ago with an issue, and he replied.